# Suppress verbose output of shell command in python

Tags: python, bash

I am running a shell command in a python script which installs ruby and rubygems using the subprocess function:

```
subprocess.call("yum install ruby rubygems -y  2>&1", shell=True)
```

In this however, the `2>&1` doesn't seem to suppress the output like in a normal bash script. Is there any other way to suppress the output?

Comment: That's a terrible way to use `subprocess`. Also, really? [*REALLY?!*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18357048/20862)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot this:

```
1>/dev/null
```

So, the result script will be:

```
subprocess.call("yum install ruby rubygems -y  2>&1 1>/dev/null", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* **need** to do this then - Use `subprocess.Popen` with stdout and stderr redirected to pipes.